# Python string indices must be integers

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm reading a Dictionary from an API which has a field called 'price'.

I'm reading it fine for a while (so, the code works) until I get to a point I get the error message: string indices must be integers.

That breaks my code.

So, I would like to find a way to skip it (ignore it) when this happens, and continue with the code. And just print something out so I know something happened.

So, far I don't manage to see what number is causing this error.

If I test this by itself, it works fine.

```
fill = {'price': 0.00002781 }
price = fill['price'] # OUTPUT: string indices must be integers
print(price)
```

I've tried many things:

```
from decimal import Decimal
price = decimal(fill['price'])
```

also:

```
price = int(fill['price']) # but it's not really an int
```

and:

```
price = float(fill['price']) # but sometimes it's a very big float so I need decimal
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that what you get from the API is not exactly what you expect:

The variable `fill` is a string (at least at the time you get the error).
As strings can't have string indices (like dictionaries can) you get the `TypeError` exception.

To handle the exception and troubleshoot it, you can use `try-except`, like so:

```
try:
    price = fill['price']
except TypeError as e:
    print(f"fill: {fill}, exception: {str(e)}")
```

This way, when there is an issue, the `fill` value will be printed as well as the exception.

Answer (score 1):

`string indices must be integers` tells you that the type of `fill` during runtime at some point is a `str` instead of `Dict`. I suggest that you add type checking or assertion to your program to make sure `fill` is of the expected type.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just ignore it you could use try and except blocks.

```
try:
  price = fill['price']
except Exception as e:
  print(f"Error reading the price. Error: {e}")
```

Comment: You miss the point here. OP expects to be able to get some value. The problem is that *fill* is not of an appropriate type. That is his issue